# How to refer to a variable from the conditional statement in the ExtractByAttributes function in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, sql

Trying to use the ExtractByAttributes for rasters so that I have multiple attribute values that I want to extract.

This works fine:
myraster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes("source_raster", "VALUE IN (1,8,10)")

but obviously I can't repeat this procedure for hundreds of layers by manually inserting the desired attribute values for each. Anything I've tried for replacing the numbers with a variable has not worked. It doesn't seem to take a list of strings or integers, nor does it help to strip the brackets[] from around the list, or to have the numbers as a single string. I've even tried with a single number instead of many and I just can't get it to work without inserting the actual number in there. What on earth am I missing? Needless to say I'm a beginner with Python.

Many thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 2):

The probelm is that arcpy is expecting a single string, including the , and (). in your case this should look like :

```
myraster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes("source_raster", "VALUE IN (" str(val1)  +"," + str(val2) + "," + str(val3) +")")
```

where val1,2 and 3 are integers.

or you can convert your list to a string before

```
s_mylist = "("
for i in mylist:
    s_mylist += (str(i) + ",")
s_mylist = s_mylist[:-1]+")"
myraster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes("source_raster", "VALUE IN " + s_mylist)
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I had tried to make it into a single string already but must have made some mistake along the way with parenthesis or sth because now with your code it seems to be working! HUGE THANKS!